# Сложная проблема с ajax

Tags: ajax, html, javascript

У меня имеется куча элементов создоваемых в цикле
http://dumpz.org/943661/
И мне надо , что бы по нажатию на кнопку данные из скрытого поля отпровлялись ajax запросов на файл обработчик , но он только отсылает первый элемент на странице , как это по другому сделать ?
Вот [пример](http://dumpz.org/941882/).

Comment: > поля с индификатором user_id

Проблема вечная... На странице **не** может быть несколько элементов с одинаковым id.

Comment: Вечная проблема #2: и**ден**тификатор, э**л**ементов  
При выборке по идентификатору браузер (и библиотеки) **всегда** будет брать только первый элемент. Идентификатор - **уникальное** имя для элемента на странице.

Answer (score 2):

Идинтификатор (id) - должен быть уникальным для каждого элемента.

Опишите подробнее ситуацию.

Вы определись по нажатия на элемент должно отправляться или по кнопке...